# Editing a registry string containing quotes

Tags: c#, string, registry

I have a registry string that contains double quotes that I have to edit. I know the \" ignores the quotes or whatever. I tried a verbatim string literal but that gave me 30+ errors. Anyone have any suggestions? Heres the block of code:

```
    RegistryKey mavroKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
    RegistryKey mavbridgeKey = mavroKey.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\MavBridge\\", true);
    mavbridgeKey.SetValue("ImagePath", " ", RegistryValueKind.String);
    mavbridgeKey.Close();
```

The string value is

```
    "C:\Mavro\MavBridge\Server\MavBridgeService.exe" /service /data "..\Data"
```

Thanks
Trevor Heins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a verbatim string, and you want to use quotes, you just need to type them twice:

```
@"""C:\Mavro\MavBridge\Server\MavBridgeService.exe"" /service /data ""..\Data"""
```

when using a normal string, you can use `\"` to include a quote, and `\\` to include a backslash:

```
"\"C:\\Mavro\\MavBridge\\Server\\MavBridgeService.exe\" /service /data \"..\\Data\""
```